# Swift libraries and Objective-C libraries together via Cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

In my Swift project I had to use `Parse`. Parse is a library written in Objective-C. So, I installed it using Cocoapods. My `Podfile` lokked like this:

```
pod 'Parse'
```

I did bridge header setup. After that I followed the quick start guide for testing Parse using official documentation. One of the code line used for testing Parse looked like this:

```
let testObject = PFObject(className: "TestObject")
        testObject["foo"] = "bar"
        testObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            print("Object has been saved.")
        }
```

Every thing worked fine. Now, I also wanted to use `Alamofire` and as it is a library written in Swift, the documentation suggested that it should be included framework so I modified my `Podfile` by adding following code:

```
pod 'Parse'

use_frameworks!
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
```

Then after doing `pod install`, I am getting error for my `Parse` code as

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'PFObject'
Use of unresolved identifier 'Parse'
Use of unresolved identifier 'PFAnalytics'
```

So, how should I install the two libraries, one written in Swift and another written in Ojective-C, in my project through Cocoapods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put `use_frameworks!` before `pod 'Parse'`

My Pod that use Almafore & Parse:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'
pod 'Alamofire'
pod 'Parse'
```

Updated: As posted by The Rohan Sanap, another thing to do is to add

```
#import Parse
```

to swift file that use this framework.

Comment: Tried this before posting question. Not working. Same error!

Comment: I've used Almafore & Parse in the same project also. In my pod, I have use_frameworks! and platform ios 8.0. But I think that the key is the use_frameworks!. Try to clean your workspace and/or call 'update pod'

Comment: Or maybe you don't have ${inherited} in your BuildSetting (Frameworks search, header search) ?

Comment: Ok! This answer worked for me. There was one thing that I was missing is that instead of doing `import Parse` in `.swift` file, I was doing `#import <Parse/Parse.h>` in bridge header file, which was wrong.